# How to center spine text with zwpagelayout

Tags: spacing, zwpagelayout

I am trying to use `zwpagelayout` to create a cover that I can use with CreateSpace. So far, I have almost everything working, but there is one problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={,10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
back cover
}\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \centering
        \begin{sideways}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont \textbf{The Title Which is Long\hspace{1in} The Author}\end{sideways}
        }\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
\begin{center}

front cover

\end{center}
}\hss}
\end{document}
```

In the above, the spine looks fine as I have it, but if I try to add a logo with:

```
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}
```

the whole spine shifts to the left and is no longer centered. In other words, replacing the line with `sideways` with:

```
\begin{sideways}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont \textbf{The Title Which is Long\hspace{1in} The Author}\end{sideways}text
```

doesn't do what I expect. How can I center some horizontal text below the author's name on my spine? Do I need to use minipages?

The following replacement for the `sideways` line almost gets me where I need to be, but I had to manually try different options for the `put` command. Can that be automated?

```
        \begin{sideways}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
        \textbf{The Title Which is Long\hspace{1in}
        The Author}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(50,-14){\turnbox{-90}{cats}}
        \end{picture}
        \end{sideways}
```

Comment: Also, when I added the `\hspace` to the spine, it caused a basically blank extra page at the beginning to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate this answer, I added the `demo` option to `graphicx` and moved it to load above `zwpagelayout` so it would take effect.

The issue you are seeing is that the sideways box was being typeset on the same "line" as your next text, top aligned.  In reality, you want to start a new line in the spine, putting the logo on the next line.  `\\[2em]`  starts a new line with `2em` of extra vertical space; adjust to your needs.

This can be achieved with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % DEMO ADDED FOR ILLUSTRATION
\usepackage[papersize={,10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
back cover
}\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \centering
        \begin{sideways}\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont \textbf{The Title Which is Long\hspace{1in} The Author}\end{sideways}
        \\[2em] \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.2cm]{logo}
        }\hss
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
\begin{center}

front cover

\end{center}
}\hss}
\end{document}
```

The cover now appears as:

[image: book]

Comment: This works wonderfully, however, I have an (unrelated) issue - using a `minibox` with \\ in it causes the file to appear with a blank page at the beginning (everything appears on page 2).

Comment: Since this question already has an accepted issue (and the new issue is unrelated), it would be best to form a new question with a MWE for this problem.