# Why does a linebreak in minipage flow this to the next page?

Tags: spacing, minipage, zwpagelayout

I am using `zwpagelayout` (see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168814/how-to-center-spine-text-with-zwpagelayout)) but if I put a `minipage` with a line or paragraph break, I get weird two-page output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={,10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,topmargin=.5in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\hbox to \textwidth{%
  \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
\begin{minipage}{5in}
This\\
Overflows
\end{minipage}

}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \centering
        }\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \centering
}\hss}
\end{document}
```

How do I use linebreaks in a `minipage` in this case?

Comment: Use `\vbox to 0.9\textheight` at all places.

Comment: why are you using `\vbox` and `\hbox` at all? they should never be used at the top level in a latex document, just use minipage.

Comment: `zwpagelayout` uses thems as examples, this makes a book cover on a single page. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

As David said in the comments, just a minipage is enough. Although this is omitted in many tutorials, you can also fix the **height of the minipages**, so you do not need at all vertical boxes of `\textheight`, since it is possible for a minipage take even the complete text area of a single page (for example, to make the cover).

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={6in,5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,  
textwidth=5in,topmargin=.5in,leftmargin=.25in,
nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fboxsep10pt\fboxrule1pt
\fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{
\begin{minipage}%
[t][\dimexpr\textheight-21pt]%
[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-21pt}%
This\\
Not\\
Overflows
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```